# I am looking to refresh a ListView without reloading the page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am looking to refresh a `ListView` without reloading the page.  More precisely I have a service that is sending data for a `ListView` in an `Activity`, however the `Activity` loads long before the `Service` can get the data.  So I need to be able to load/reload the `ListView` after the `Activity` has already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ListView`'s `Adapter` whenever you want to refresh it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that [`notifyDataSetChanged` only works if you use the `add`, `insert`, `remove`, and `clear` functions on the `Adapter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426), so I ended up doing it the following way in a similar implementation:

An `AsyncTask` fetches all the data in `doInBackground`. Then, when finished I set the list adapter for the first time in `onPostExecute`. To let the user know that something is loading, I just put a `TextView` on top of the `Listview` and set its text to "Loading.." in `onPreExecute` and then make it invisible in `onPostExecute` when the data is ready.

If you need to refresh the data, you just execute the `AsyncTask` again.

I like this way because you are only setting the `ArrayAdapter` once (i.e. when you finally have all the data). [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is more on AsyncTask in case you need it. The docs have some nice example code.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to use `IntentService` instead of `Service`. By, using `IntentService` you will be able to send data to the background `Service` and also receive the updated data while firing a `BroadCastReceiver` to update your UI. [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) is a complete example how you can achieve your task using an `IntentService`.